# Nuget SQLite to use with Dapper without loading Entity Framework dependencies

Tags: c#, sqlite, dapper, nuget-package, system.data.sqlite

In my *c#* application, I would like to use *SQLite*  with **Dapper** (on `SqliteConnection`).

The problem with current *nuget* *System.Data.SQLite* version is that *EntityFramework*-related dependencies are also loaded, but they are not needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**System.Data.SQLite.Core** is the package, which contains `SqliteConnection` and doesn't have any dependencies to EF.